# Is there a difference between ifstream::binary and ios::binary?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I've seen code written like so:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("largefile.dat", ifstream::binary | ifstream::in);
```

Now this makes me confused, is there any difference at all between the above code and this code below using `ios::binary` and `ios::in` as replacement?

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("largefile.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference. These names are inherited from the virtual base [`std::ios_base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base) from which the concrete stream classes derive.

Answer (score 2):

From *Josuttis N.M. - The Standard Library A Tutorial and Reference*.

Chapter 15.2 *Fundamental Stream Classes and Stream Objects*

> The stream classes of the IOStream library form a hierarchy:

[image]

> The classes in this class hierarchy play the following roles:
> 1. The base class `ios_base` **defines the properties of all stream classes** independent of the character type and the corresponding character traits. Most of this class consists of components and functions for state and format flags.
> 2. The class template `basic_ios<>` is derived from `ios_base` and defines the common properties
>   of all stream classes that depend on the character types and the corresponding character
>   traits. These properties include the definition of the buffer used by the stream. The buffer is an
>   object of a class derived from the template class `basic_streambuf<>` with the corresponding
>   template instantiation. It performs the actual reading and/or writing.
> 3. The class templates `basic_istream<>` and `basic_ostream<>` derive virtually from
>   `basic_ios<>` and define objects that can be used for reading or writing, respectively. Like
>   `basic_ios<>`, these classes are templates that are parametrized with a character type and its
>   traits. When internationalization does not matter, the corresponding instantiations for the character
>   type char — `istream` and `ostream` — are used.
> 4. The class template `basic_iostream<>` derives from both `basic_istream<>` and
>   `basic_ostream<>`. This class template defines objects that can be used for both reading and
>   writing.
>  5. The class template `basic_streambuf<>` is the heart of the IOStream library. This class
>   defines the interface to all representations that can be written to or read from by streams and is
>   used by the other stream classes to perform the reading and writing of characters. For access to
>   some external representation, classes are derived from `basic_streambuf<>`.